# Inconsistent results with SqlDataAdapter.Fill and SqlDataReader.Read

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, datatable

I have a SQL database with various tables that I want to read into DataTable objects.  To do this I used SqlDataAdapter.Fill, which worked perfectly for all but one table, called "Problems".  On this table the method runs without throwing any exceptions, but the resulting DataTable only ends up with 3,321 rows, whereas the SQL table has 9,800 rows.  My code for the "Problems" table was the same as for the other tables:

```
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Problems]", my_connection);
adapter.Fill(my_dataset, "Problems");
```

I listened for adapter.FillError and adapter.RowUpdated error statuses, but caught nothing.  So I decided to read the table in sequentially with a SqlDataReader (code below).  This worked fine and grabbed the full 9,800 rows.  This caused me to worry that using SqlDataAdapter.Fill might be missing data for the other tables, so I generalized the method I wrote for SqlDataReader to let me read any table sequentially (code also below).  But when I tried to use this generalized method, I again only got 3,321 rows!

I want to be able to read my SQL database into DataTables without worrying that I'm losing data.

Code for sequential read for "Problems" (this is the code that actually works):

```
    public static DataTable GetAllProblems()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Problems");

        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ExerciseID", typeof(int)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ParentID", typeof(int)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AnswerFields", typeof(string)));

        table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { table.Columns[0] };

        DataRow dr;

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Problems]", ProblemDBPortConnection());
        if (com == null) throw new Exception("WTF");

        string a;
        int ex_id, parent_id;

        com.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
        while(rdr.Read())
        {
            dr = table.NewRow();
            a = rdr["Answers"].ToString();
            ex_id = (int)rdr["ExerciseID"];

            parent_id = -1;
            if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(rdr["ParentID"])) parent_id = (int)rdr["ParentID"];

            dr["ExerciseID"] = ex_id;
            dr["ParentID"] = parent_id;
            dr["AnswerFields"] = ProblemAnswerFields(a);
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        rdr.Close();
        com.Connection.Close();

        return table;
    }
```

Next is the generalization of the above method, which on the "Problems" table seems to fail in the same sneaky way as the SqlDataAdapter.Fill method.  In my code I call the method by

```
my_dataset.Tables.Add(GetTable("Problems", "SELECT * FROM [Problems]", new Tuple<string, Type>("ExerciseID", typeof(int)), new Tuple<string, Type>("ParentID", typeof(int)), new Tuple<string, Type>("AnswerFields", typeof(string))));
```

and the method itself is

```
    public static DataTable GetTable(string tableName, string selectCommand, params Tuple<string, Type>[] fields)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(selectCommand, ProblemDBConnection());
        if(com==null)
            throw new Exception("WTF");

        if(fields.Length == 0)
            throw new Exception("WTF");

        DataTable table = new DataTable(tableName);
        DataColumn dc;
        for(int i=0; i<fields.Length; i++)
        {
            if(fields[i].Item2 == typeof(string))
                dc = new DataColumn(fields[i].Item1, typeof(string));
            else
            {
                if(fields[i].Item2 != typeof(int))
                    throw new Exception("WTF");
                dc = new DataColumn(fields[i].Item1, typeof(int));
            }

            table.Columns.Add(dc);
        }

        table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {table.Columns[0]};

        com.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
        DataRow dr;
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            dr = table.NewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fields[i].Item1 == "AnswerFields")
                {
                    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(rdr["Answers"]))
                        dr[fields[i].Item1] = "";
                    else 
                        dr[fields[i].Item1] = ProblemAnswerFields(rdr["Answers"].ToString());
                }
                else if (DBNull.Value.Equals(rdr[fields[i].Item1]))
                {
                    if (fields[i].Item2 == typeof(string))
                        dr[fields[i].Item1] = "";
                    else
                    {
                        dr[fields[i].Item1] = -1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (fields[i].Item2 == typeof(string))
                        dr[fields[i].Item1] = rdr[fields[i].Item1].ToString();
                    else
                    {
                        dr[fields[i].Item1] = (int)rdr[fields[i].Item1];
                    }
                }
            }

            table.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        rdr.Close();
        com.Connection.Close();

        return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, turns out I was accidentally using an old connection in the cases that failed, which pulled all the data from a deprecated version of the database.  ><  It would appear that I'm not very bright.